# Export all sheets as pdf

Tags: vba, pdf, export

I'm trying to create a macro which i  need to print all the sheets in the macro enabled workbook. However i need to print only the visible cells in each sheets. ie i have hidden rows and columns in the sheets. All the values in the sheets are dynamic which can change any time .

```
Sub Print_sheet()

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array(1, 2)).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Test\MI team\aa.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, 
IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
 IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

End Sub
```

is there any way to do it ? please advise

Comment: write specialcells(xlvisible) to intermediate sheets and pdf them and then delete. E.g. https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/956967-vba-save-only-visible-cells-pdf.html

Comment: I've tried with the link, my concern is i have more than 10 worksheets with me . i need to print only the visible cells in some sheets but for some other sheets i have graphs and charts so all this should be incorporate into one macro.

Comment: select case worksheet.name do ........ case .... do something else Not the most efficient way. I would declare an array holding the sheets you copy in the entirety and have that as a one line copy paste in the same code as your loop that copies your visible ranges to intermediate sheets, those intermediate sheets are copied as an array across and then deleted from original. Really should have these as separate functions/subs but can be done in one without too much code.